# Prove that the function $f:G \rightarrow G$ given by $f(a^i)=b^i$ is an automorphism of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing

Assume that $a$ and $b$ are both generators of the cyclic group $G$, so that $G=\langle a \rangle $ and $G= \langle b \rangle$. Prove that the function $f: G \rightarrow G$ given by $f(a^i)=b^i$ is an automorphism of $G$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: Try asking for help instead of ordering us to solve the problem.

Comment: Following basic ettiquete will get Jewelss more and better help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying that $f$ is an automorphism of $G$ is equivalent to saying that $f$ is a bijective homomorphism.

To see that $f$ is a homomorphism note that for any $i, j \in \mathbb{N}$ we have
$$f(a^i a^j) = f(a^{i+j}) = b^{i+j} = b^i b^j = f(a^i) f(a^j).$$

Furthermore $f$ is clearly surjective because the generator $b$ of the group $G$ lies in the image of $f$. But $f$ is also injective because
$$kernel(f) = \{ g \in G; f(g) = e \} = \{ a^i; i \in \mathbb{N}, f(a^i)=b^i=e \} = \{ e \}$$
where $e \in G$ is the neutral element of $G$ (note that since $b$ generates the group $G$ we have $f(a^i)=b^i=e$ if and only if $i=0$).

Hence $f$ is also bijective and thus an automorphism.

Comment: "the generator $b$ of the group $G$ lies in the image of $f$" implies that $f$ is surjective, not bijective. You need something more.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Quite an embarrassing mistake I must admit...

Comment: Tom, how do you know that f(a^i)=b^i=e i.f.f i =0? I'm having trouble seeing this. I know that each g in G can be expressed as some power of b, but why can't the identity be hit by two powers of b?

Answer (score 0):

The function is clearly an homorphism.

It is an automorphism because it has an inverse, i.e $$g : G \to G$$ $$g(b^{i}) = a^{i}$$